# How to show by example that existence of barrier function of any set $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ is dependent of its set?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, potential-theory

How to show that there a set that has no barrier function?
I mean that how to show by example that existence of barrier function of any set $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ is dependent of its set.

Definition (barrier function):

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $z_0 \in \partial U$. Let $b:U \leftarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $b$ is barrier function of $U$ in $z_0$, if

(i) $b$ is continuous in $U$

(ii) b is subharmonic in closure of $U$ ($\Delta b \leq 0$)

(iii) $b(z) \leq 0$, $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$

(iv) $b(z)=0$ **if and only if** $z=z_0$.

Comment: Poor $b$...less than harmonious...

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $U$? For example, what if $U$ is the punctured disc $B(z_0,r) \setminus \{z_0\}$, and pick $z_0 \in \partial U$ as above?

Comment: No there isn't. Problem is I don't see how to construct a set that causes some conditions to fail. I know that is $U=\mathbb{D}$, then for example $b(z)=|z|-1$ is boundary function of $\mathbb{D}$ for all $z_0 \in \partial \mathbb{D}$, because it satisfies all conditions.

Comment: Your example vanishes everywhere on the boundary of the disc, which seems to contradict your condition (iv) unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: it satisfies condition (iv), because $b(z)=|z|-1=1-1=0$ when $z=z_0\in \partial \mathbb{D}$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I fixed the wording, but incidentally, harmonious functions [are now a thing](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22harmonious+functions%22).

Comment: @laovultai No, (iv) fails because it has "if and only if".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example was suggested by Christopher A. Wong in a comment. Let $U$ be a set such that $\partial U$ has an isolated point. Take this point as $z_0$. Then there is no $b$ as above, because (iii) and (iv) contradict the maximum principle for subharmonic functions (and $b$ is subharmonic in a neighborhood of $z_0$ by virtue of (ii)).